# What is the state-of-art in extracting Noun Phrases from a textual content?

Tags: nlp, machine-learning

I am looking at Stanford NLP Parser for extracting noun phrases from a text. Is there something better that can be used for free?

Comment: "State of the Art" is often not "free".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say about better, but there are a lot of them for free
[LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/), [OpenNLP](http://incubator.apache.org/opennlp/), [Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/), [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (Python)

Answer (score 5):

If you're working on English data, check out the [Illinois chunker](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/13). I've yet to try it out, but it's pretty new and the folks at Illinois tend to write good NLP software.

Update: the project is available on github now: https://github.com/IllinoisCogComp/illinois-cogcomp-nlp/tree/master/chunker